# Swift force cast Bool to Int error when creating key/value pairs in dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

TLDR: Trying to create a dictionary with type [String]/[Any] with Key containing arrays of mixed data types. Then trying to loop through and create a new dict with just the Key and Bool Value results in a force cast error.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Long version:

I have 4 arrays I need to convert (2 String, 1 Bool, 1 Int) into a dictionary. I created a dictionary with the Key of type String and the Value of type Any as I need one of the String arrays to be the Key and the rest to be contained in an array as the Value. Like this:

```
var dict1: [String: [Any]] = [:]
```

Then I loop through the previously mentioned arrays and create key/value pairs:

Edit: `i = 0`

```
//i-1 to match iteration with array position
while i < dict1.count {
    i += 1
    dict1[stringArray1[i-1]] = [intArray[i-1], boolArray[i-1], stringArray2[i-1]]
}
```

When I print the dictionary, it contains the correct Key/Value pairs.

Now I need to create a dictionary with just the Key from dict1 and Bool array values from the key. So I've set up an empty array like this:

```
var dict2: [String: [Bool]] = [:]
```

and tried to create KeyValue pairs like this:

```
for (string, bool) in dict1 {
dict2[string] = bool
}
```

I get an error saying I need to force cast to type Bool. Force casting to type Bool creates an error saying swift can't convert an Int to a Bool. I tried changing the type of the Key in dict2 to type Int, and got an error saying to forecast to type Int. Doing so says Swift can't force Bool to Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: 
this will help you with cast

```
var dict2: [String: [Bool]] = [:]
var dict1: [String: [Any]] = ["a" : [1], "b" : [true], "c": [false], "d" : ["e"]]
for (string, bool) in dict1 {

    dict2[string] = bool.flatMap({$0 as? Bool})
}
```

---

This is an example how can you filter and cast [string:any] dictionary to [string:bool]

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["a" : 1, "b" : true, "c": false]

let casted = dict.filter{$0.value is Bool}.reduce([String: Bool]()) { (dictionary, nextValue) -> [String: Bool] in
    var mutableDictionary = dictionary
    mutableDictionary[nextValue.key] = nextValue.value as? Bool
    return mutableDictionary
}
```

I think there will be no problem for you to follow this and cast [String:[Any]] to [String:[Bool]]

Comment: Thanks very much, I think the problem I'm having is where the values are arrays. My dictionary is set up like Key: [int, bool, string]. I can't figure out in your example how to access the bool value in the value's array. I can access it normally with dict2[1]

Comment: I meant bool[1] in the for loop

Comment: alright I read up on filters some and see that I shouldn't need to access a specific element of the array.
Now the error is `error: cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [Bool]]' with an index of type '(String).Type' (aka 'String.Type')`

Comment: Thanks much... I had some errors in my logic causing those errors. It's working now :)